# Start Page bookmarks and settings in regards to privacy

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security

Using the Tor Browser, is it safe to use bookmarks on Start Page?  When using or saving settings, is it safe to to use URL option?

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly safe to do this as long as you know for a fact that the website in question is not in any danger of having some sort of javascript exploit like we saw in 2013.  I personaly have my browser set to open a picture of "trust no one" from x-files upon opening.